# Synch / asynch d-type flip flop in vhdl

Tags: testing, asynchronous, vhdl, synchronous, flip-flop

I've some problems with VHDL's configuration.
I should make a simple D-TYPE FLIP FLOP with two different architectures. One should be synchronous and the other asynchronous. The code of the entity is

```
entity FD is
Port (  D:  In  std_logic;
    CK: In  std_logic;
    RESET:  In  std_logic;
    Q:  Out std_logic);
end FD;


architecture SYNCH of FD is 

begin
PSYNCH: process(CK,RESET)
begin
  if CK'event and CK='1' then 
    if RESET='1' then 
      Q <= '0'; 
    else
      Q <= D; 
    end if;
  end if;
end process;

end SYNCH;

architecture ASYNCH of FD is 

begin

PASYNCH: process(CK,RESET)
begin
  if RESET='1' then
    Q <= '0';
  elsif CK'event and CK='1' then 
    Q <= D; 
  end if;
end process;

end ASYNCH;


configuration CFG_FD_ASYNCH of FD is
for ASYNCH
end for;
end CFG_FD_ASYNCH;


configuration CFG_FD_SYNCH of FD is
for SYNCH
end for;
end CFG_FD_SYNCH;
```

The code of the test bench is

```
entity TBFD is
end TBFD;

architecture TEST of TBFD is

signal  CK:     std_logic :='0';
signal  RESET:      std_logic :='0';
signal  D:      std_logic :='0';
signal  QSYNCH:     std_logic;
signal  QASYNCH:    std_logic;

component FD

Port (  CK: In  std_logic;
    RESET:  In  std_logic;
    D:  In  std_logic;
    Q:  Out std_logic);
end component;

begin 

FD_SYNCH : FD
Port Map ( CK, RESET, D, QSYNCH); 

FD_ASYNCH : FD
Port Map ( CK, RESET, D, QASYNCH); 


RESET <= '0', '1' after 0.6 ns, '0' after 1.1 ns, '1' after 2.2 ns, '0' after 3.2 ns;   


D <= '0', '1' after 0.4 ns, '0' after 1.1 ns, '1' after 1.4 ns, '0' after 1.7 ns, '1' after        1.9 ns;


PCLOCK : process(CK)
begin
    CK <= not(CK) after 0.5 ns; 
end process;

end TEST;

configuration FDTEST of TBFD is
  for TEST

  for FD_SYNCH : FD
     use configuration WORK.CFG_FD_SYNCH; 
  end for;

  for FD_ASYNCH : FD
     use configuration WORK.CFG_FD_ASYNCH; 
  end for;

  end for;
end FDTEST;
```

The problem is during the test bench. The waveform of the synchronous part ( QSYNCH signal wave) is always equal to the asynchronous one ( QASYNCH signal wave). How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>In the absence of a binding indication in the two FD configurations the architecture used will be the last analyzed - the default binding.  (This says you CFD_FD_ASYNCH and CFD_FD_SYNCH, which supply no useful information aren't necessary other than to satisfy your original FD_TEST configuration specification).</del>

This works as an alternative from the top level:

```
configuration FDTEST of TBFD is

  for TEST

      for FD_SYNCH : FD
         use entity work.FD(synch);
      end for;

      for FD_ASYNCH : FD
         use entity work.FD(asynch);
      end for;

  end for;
end FDTEST;
```

And when FDTEST is simulated yields:

[image: asynchronous reset when entity and architecture bound in configuration]

### I was wrong about your problem

After your comment that QSYNCH and QASYNCH were still the same ( nothing changed) I took a harder look and found out there was nothing wrong with your original configuration.

The configuration declarations found in the configuration specifications CFG_FD_SYNCH and CFG_FD_ASYNCH are perfectly capable of declaring the architecture used in their respective FDTEST configuration specification instances.

It's legal VHDL (you'll notice it has no analysis errors).  I originally mistook the block configurations for something else from lack of attention while multitasking.

That said your problem isn't configuration but lies somewhere else. Either your original configuration specifications or the one I demonstrated are both capable of doing the right thing.  When you commented that it made no difference and you were apparently still getting QASYNCH waveform results on both flip flops I did a quick search on how that could happen.

Unfortunately I got busy before I could document it properly, but the only way I found that you could get both waveforms showing QASYNCH behavior (asynchronous reset) is because you aren't elaborating and simulating the configuration FDTEST, instead you are elaborating and simulating TBFD (the test bench).

Both Flip Flops outputs show the asynchronous reset behavior because the ASYNCH architecture is the last analyzed and you aren't simulating the elaborated configuration.  Under those conditions it doesn't matter if the configuration specifications are present in the working library or not, you aren't using them.

And that appears to be the actual problem.

Elaborating and simulating TBFD instead of FDTEST you get a waveform that looks like this:

[image: tbfd showing QASYNCH and QSYNCH matching]

Which should match what you've been relating to us.

Elaborating and simulating FDTEST using your original code gives a waveform identical to the first one shown above.

You haven't indicated which VHDL tool you're using making it hard to tell you how to elaborate and simulate the configuration FDTEST.  You might need a manual, cheat sheet or other source demonstrating how to elaborate a configuration (which is a primary unit) and invoke it for simulation.

Comment: Thank you, but for me it doesn't work. The result is the same. Can be the ModelSim software the problem?

Comment: I change 
    `use configuration WORK.CFG_FD_SYNCH;`
in
    `use entity work.FD(synch);`
and 
    `use configuration WORK.CFG_FD_ASYNCH;` 
in 
    `use entity work.FD(asynch);`
Nothing changes .

Comment: @MI89 - I pointed out the actual error in the answer. My answer wasn't originally accurate, your configuration is capable of being used.  See the answer for an explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much. You solve my problem. I always simulate the test bench entity file and not the config file. Thanks again.

Comment: The good news is with replacing the left off context clauses your code did exactly what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Remove RESET signal from the sensitivity list for the D Filp Flop Asynchronous Program. If you add reset signal in sensitivity list then the changes in reset signal is sensitive to clock change.